# Xamarin Forms Error MT5303

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm getting Error MT5303 and I've already read this link :
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/
but I don't understand **how and where** should I use
**[LinkWith ("mylib.a", Frameworks = "SystemConfiguration")]**
example of error :

> Error 4   MT5303:Native linking warning: warning: can't parse dwarf
>   compilation unit info in
>   /Users/sohrab/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/FormsTemplateiOS/2a0e4ab7-d8b6-4ec8-8fda-ce9f9ce17f50/output/temp/mtouch-cache/Cirrious.CrossCore.dll.armv7.o
>         0   0

thanks in advance.

Comment: I't very hard to understand what you're asking. Could you please give more context on the type of project you're trying to compile, how you're compiling it and so on.

Comment: Can you add a link to the full build output? There might be more important information there.

Answer (score 0):

`[LinkWith]` is an assembly level attribute. You usually add it in your `Property.cs` file, but that's not mandatory.

```cs
[assembly:LinkWith ("mylib.a", Frameworks = "SystemConfiguration")]
```